# Disconnecting windows software RAID disks without requiring a resync

Tags: windows, windows-10, raid

I have a working 3TB software RAID volume under Windows 10 on my primary work machine, physically two 3TB rotating rust disk. The boot volume is a separate NVMe SSD. The RAID volume resynchronisation process after e.g. a power loss requires like 5 hours of uninterrupted on time.

Just did a simple experiment:

- Reboot, logon, check volumes are in sync, orderly power off. I know from past experience that if at this point I'd make a reboot, logon, check volume status, I'd find the RAID in sync.
- Disconnect power to both 3TB drives, reboot, logon, orderly power off.
- Reconnect power to both 3TB drives, reboot, logon, check volume status.

The RAID resynchronisation process has started. I conclude the mere fact of seeing both drives disconnected is recorded on the Windows boot volume on the NVMe drive, and enough to trigger a resync.

How can I avoid this? I'd prefer something I can do before reconnecting the drives, but I'm willing to do something before disconnecting them.

---

Original motivation and report:

Sometime I want to make things with that PC that I know are likely to crash. Yesterday that was scavenging a friend's M.2 SSD that, it turns out, has grown bad blocks that cause a bios warning and somehow prevent Windows from booting, including from another volume. So I

- verified my RAID volume was in sync, powered down my machine
- disconnected the power connectors of the two rotating rust drives, connected the faulty M.2 on a secondary port
- tried to boot Windows from my NVMe on the primary port; it went spinning cursor for like 15 minutes
- connected a Linux USB key, reset, booted on that, extracted critical data from the faulty M.2 SSD
- powered off, removed the faulty M.2 SSD, reconnected the power connectors
- rebooted Windows from the NVMe.

To my dismay, the RAID resynchronisation process started.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the RAID drives didn't see any changes during that process, but you should even be able to disconnect a drive in the array when offline, and for example do a non volatile surface scan. If the rebuilding process kicks in, something has changed on one (or maybe even both) of the drives (which could indicate deteriorating health).

You may want to do that scan on each of the drives to see if they're still healthy. I'm not sure if you're running software or hardware raid, but the safest is probably to power it down, and do a surface scan each of the drives separately (read only!) using a bootable tool. Hardware RAID means you'll have to switch ports or change RAID to JBOD setting on the card's bios.

Longer term, I would strongly suggest leaving RAID behind. As you have noticed, the rebuilding process takes an increasingly long time (I think it was about 36h when I last used 4TB drives on an Areca RAID card). During that window, the other drive could fail as well, as you probably bought those two simultaneously and they've seen exactly the same wear and tear.

Comment: I'm quite confident the disks are healthy, and the resync was not caused by writing to them. I now describe an experiment which I think demonstrates that what triggers the resync is booting with the disk disconnected, which gets recorded somewhere, presumably on my NVMe boot volume (I doubt that's on the motherboard or in the cloud). I'm aware of the limitations of RAID that you point out, use RAID5 with 4 drives on a NAS for other data, plus a separate backup strategy. Can't remember loosing important data due to drive failure since 1995.

Comment: Doesn't hurt testing them to rule this out though, whatever the suspected cause is. This is usually my first stop as it requires relatively little effort (it's mostly waiting after all). Considering their size (1.5TB) I assume they're already a number of years old :)

Comment: The disks are ST3000DM001-9YN166 (3TB), and quite old. One has 31951 power-on hours, the other 1064 (formerly a cold spare). Both passed their extended test a month ago, and show no alarming SMART data. Again I'm confident what triggers the resync is Windows recording that I booted with the drives disconnected.

Comment: I vaguely recall that only about a third of drive failures are preceded by SMART related warnings, but it is up to you of course. Interested to see if it is the mechanism you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the SSD is certified for Windows Server 2016 and Windows Server 2019 using the Windows Server Catalog Ask the vendor if the drive is compatible with Storage Spaces DirectUse storage management software to check the status of the drives on the storage.Use storage management software to check the status of the drives on the storage.Make sure all nodes have the latest Windows updates installed. Update storage and drive firmware if necessary.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).